# TINA-TI convergence problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer

I am trying to simulate the following circuit in TINA-Ti and I am facing the following convergence problem. Please help me to resolve this.

[image: Circuit]

[image: Convergence problem]

Comment: You may get a more precise answer/explanation of the convergence problem by contacting the developpers of TINA directly. They should be able to reproduce the problem on their system and give you a solution much quicker ...

Comment: No decoupling capacitors?